# Finding Context free grammar from a language

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar

I am trying to construct context-free grammar from the following language accepted by this  [PDA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQpS2.jpg)

$L(A)=\{a^n c^m b^{2n} \mid n, m \in {\Bbb N}, m \geqslant 2 \}$

I am particularly stuck on how to construct the grammar showing "c" with non-terminal cnsidering to be equal or greater than two

My attempt so far

$S \to e \mid aSbb \mid A$

$A \to ccA$

It is one of the concept I struggle the most now and any help is very appreciate. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

What you have is quite close to what you need, but it has two shortcomings: there is no terminal derivation from $A$, so the only terminal derivation is the one that gives you the empty word, and $A$ can only generate even numbers of $c$s. Make this small change:

$$\begin{align*}
&S\to aSbb\mid cA\\
&A\to cA\mid c
\end{align*}$$

Now every derivation that does not produce the empty word looks like this:

$$S\Rightarrow^n a^nSb^{2n}\Rightarrow a^ncAb^{2n}\Rightarrow^ka^nc^{k+1}Ab^{2n}\Rightarrow a^nc^{k+2}b^{2n}\;,$$

where $n,k\ge 0$.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much, at least I see I was close enough, so that's a progress :D

Comment: @Yani: You’re welcome.

Comment: If I am not wrong, $S \to \epsilon$ should not be a production of your grammar, since the empty word is not in $L(A)$.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: You’re right: I carried it from the OP’s grammar and forgot that we had to have two $c$s. Thanks.